# Android increment score mysql php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to increment a value in mysql table by 1 from the android app. Once, successful I am trying to launch a new activity. I have included the android and php code below. The DB is correctly being updaated on the click of the button but I cannot figure out why the new activity isnt launch. I'm sure its something minor but I cannot figure it out, any help would be much appreciated. I have included the new activity in the manifest.

Android - MainActivity

```
package com.example.conn.updatescore;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button updateScore;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.14/updatemysql/update_control.php";
    private StringRequest request;
    public static final String teamName = "Justice league";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        updateScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateScore);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        updateScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS " + jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashMap.put("name", teamName.toString());

                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SuccessActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by conn on 09/08/2017.
 */

public class SuccessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.success);
    }
}
```

update_control.php

```
class Update {

    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct(){

        $this->db = new DB_Connection();
        $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
    }

    public function update_score($name){

        $query = " UPDATE `team` SET `member` = member+1 WHERE name = '$name'";
        $is_inserted = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);

        if ($is_inserted ==1){
            $json['success'] = 'score updated' .$name;

        }else {
            $json['error'] = 'failed';
        }

        echo json_encode($json);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

}

$update = new Update();

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if (!empty($name)){
        $update->update_score($name);
    } else{
        echo ("name not set");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code to start the activity is run? Do you see the "SUCCESS ..." toast?

Comment: Did you make sure that no exception is thrown in the `onResponse`?

Comment: Post your json object sucess structure here to better help

Comment: I don't see the SUCCESS toast

Comment: There is no exception thrown

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your `try` block and step through to verify the response back to your app is correct and what you're expecting

Comment: @cmc12345 so You probably have a `JSONException` thrown. Look at logcat for the stacktrace that you printed. Or put a breakpoint in the catch. and check if it hits

Comment: I have used the same code from another example but that example works fine

Comment: @cmc12345 Maybe your JSON is different from the example. Try to put a breakpoint at the top of the try and execute line by line and see where it crash. Or even just if the `onResponse` is called at all

Comment: ok so this is what the debugger gave

Comment: it said all the variables in the config file are undefined but then i dont get why the DB is being update fine

Comment: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-12 00:58:04.235 2377-2377/com.example.conn.articulateone W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-12 00:58:04.236 2377-2377/com.example.conn.articulateone W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Comment: i have just uploaded a logcat error. Think it is to do with the json exception but i dont know why this is occuring